# how to insert gravity newsletter subscription form in template

Tags: templates, customization, plugin-gravity-forms

i have created a template.
i want to insert gravity form for newsletter subscription form in the middle of the page,content will be first name,last name,email id and subscribe button.And after click on button the thank you message.
i don't know how to do it.
please help me its urgent request.

Answer (score 0):

Read the documentation before posting questions.

https://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/article/creating-a-form/
https://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/article/embedding-a-form/